# Using Invoke-Command but get error 'One or more computer names are not valid'

Tags: powershell

> Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid

I'm getting the error when running this command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Targets -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

`$Targets` is an array, which is populated by this command:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '$Filter'" -SearchBase $OU |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
    Sort-Object
```

The computer names usually have `-` in them, but I tested computers without any special characters and got the same result.

Here is my method:

```
function Get-FilteredADComputers
{
     [CmdletBinding()]
     [OutputType([System.String[]])]
   param
       (
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet('Site 1', 'Site 2', 'Site 3')]
    [String]
    $Site,

    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet('Client', 'Server')]
    [String]
    $ComputerType,
    [Parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory)]
    [String]
    $Filter
    )

$siteSecondLevel
switch($Site){
    "site 1"{$siteSecondLevel = "LVL 1"}
    "site 2"{$siteSecondLevel = "LVL 2"}
    "site 3"{$siteSecondLevel = "LVL 3"}
}
$OU = "OU=$ComputerType,OU=Devices,OU=$siteSecondLevel,OU=$Site,OU=MyOU,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like $Filter} -SearchBase $OU | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object
}
```

How I declare my list in a test environment:

```
 $temp = Get-FilteredADComputers -Site Site1 -ComputerType Client -Filter 
"myfilter"
$target = @()

foreach($t in $temp){
    if($t -ne $null -or $t -ne ""){
       $target += $t
       }
}
```

I also get the same result by just declaring my array as `$Targets = Get-FilteredADComputers`

Comment: Can you invoke the command against each computer separately (from `$targets`) until you hit the one(s) causing problems?

Comment: I did some testing, and even though my array is populated, I get `Invoke-Command: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value.`

Comment: What't the output of `$targets` ?

Comment: @DanStef `$Targets` properly outputs the name of the computer, but `Invoke-Command` still says it's `null`

Comment: Can you confirm that you have an array of `String` objects by running `$Targets[0].GetType()`. Additionally can you confirm that there are no scoping issues, i.e. the snippets posted aren't in different codeblocks `{ ... }`

Comment: @Jacob Hi, I can confirm that the scoping is not an issue. However, $Targets is used across different modules, but I tested within one script and the result still is the same. As for the type, I noticed that $Targets[0].GetType returns null, but $Targets[1].GetType() returns the correct computer name as a String. It seems like my method is adding the it to `index 1`, not `ìndex 0`

Answer (score 1):

The $Targets is a list right? If not than do this: `$Targets2 = @($Targets)`
This will make it as a list and probably you will succeed with using this solution.

It should work, however, I would say to use a Foreach instead.

```
foreach ($Target in $Targets)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Target -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
}
```

I do it this way most of the time, as it is easier to troubleshoot and find the cause of error.

Comment: `$Targets` is already a list. I've also tried using the `foreach` but the result is the same.

Comment: Whats the content of `target` when it fails? Can you reproduce it manually? i.e. `$target=$targets[0]' then `$target=$targets[1]' and so on...

Comment: @DanStef It seems like my method is adding elements from `index 1` and up. So when `Invoke-Command` tries `index 0` of `$Targets`, it fails. I have added my method to the question, maybe you can spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In your previous comment you said you are using the `$targets += $temp`. Have you declared the $Targets as $Targets = @() ? This could cause the skipping of the first index.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to look to see what's in $targets. I suspect you may have a blank line at the end or some other oddity that Invoke-Command rejects as a computer name

Comment: In my program, I*m testing the input like this: `$temp = Get-FilteredADComputers -Site $site -ComputerType $computerType -Filter $filter
                                                                                                                       
   if($temp -ne $null -or $temp -ne ""){
        $targets += $temp
        }`. From what I can see, it does not add any blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$temp = Get-FilteredADComputers
$targets = @() 

foreach($t in $temp)
{
    if($t -ne $null -and $temp -ne "")
    {
        $targets += $t
    }
}
```

In one of your comments you said that you do the following:

```
$temp = Get-FilteredADComputers -Site $site -ComputerType $computerType -Filter $filter 
if($temp -ne $null -or $temp -ne ""){ $targets += $temp }
```

But with the check `$temp -ne $null` you just check that it's not null, as soon as there is one entry in `$temp` (even if it is just on the 2nd position) it is not null anymore..

Comment: The thing is, I think `Get-FilteredADComputers` is the problem here. When just running that method, it already skips an index. Do you have any idea why `Get-FilteredADComputers` would add at index 1?

Comment: No. I tried it at my computer and it does not start at index 1, no matter what I tried.. Your problem is somewhere else

Comment: Then it must be how I declare the array. I tried running the method in a standalone script, where I assign `Get-FIlteredADComputers` to a test variable. It still adds to index 1.

Comment: Then how do you declare your array? How do you call the function Get-FilteredAdCompuers? Add as much information as possible to your question.

Comment: I just edited. I will continue to add information if I find any weird behavior.

Comment: It now works when a single computer is passed, but if it's an array, it fails even though the array size is correct and each element is correct in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for google search purposes.  My issue was that I was trying to pass a DevOps variable to a powershell script. I had to change my DevOps `WebServers` variable

From:

```
server1,server2,server3
```

to:

```
@("server1","server2","server3")
```

and in my powershell I used:

```
$p = "$(password)";
$sv = $(WebServers);  // --> I had to change this line and remove the quotes
$u = "$(username)";
```